# How to make reusable code in yii 1.1 between controller and command?

Tags: yii, yii-components

What is the best way to reuse code between controller and command?
I have some use where the very same logic should be executed inside controller and in command as well. What is the best approach to share code? To create a component and the call this component methods from controller and command?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class (model, service, etc), and use that in the different areas.
Within the `config/main.php` or `config/console.php` there is an import section:

`'import'   => array(
                'application.models.*',
                'application.components.*',`

You can add your class anywhere really, as long as its location is referenced within the `import` section in the config, as that is how Yii1 autoloads files.